# EntityFramework and MySQL with LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EntityFramework to work with MySQL database from c#.
I'm using MySQL Connector 6.3.3, but i'm unable to use the linq syntax like

```
context.Items.Where(x => x.Id == 3)
```

I only see the following overload for Where:

```
Where(string predicate, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
```

Is there a provider or something that could help me to work with MySQL from EF with the common LINQ syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably missing a using clause :

```
using System.Linq;
```

You also need to reference the System.Core assembly.

The `Where` method you're seeing is the one defined by the `ObjectSet<T>`. The other query operators are extension methods defined in the `System.Linq.Queryable` class

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Shame on me - forgot such an easy thing :)